# Binary to image in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone

My app retrieves file content from remote server. File can be image or text. When the file is image it returns some string like this:
**????\bNExif\0\0MM\0*\0\0\0\b\0\a\0....** and so on. As I understand it's an image but in other format (binary?).

So how can I convert that string to an image and set it to  control as source?

Thanks.

Comment: you first need to find out what format the image is - jpeg/bmp/png...etc.

Comment: how are you retrieving the data, can you post the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do something like this:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.SetSource(ms);
```

Then if you have an Image element in XAML, say XamlImage:

```
XamlImage.Source = bi;
```